# Bigquery array of STRINGs to array of INTs

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to pull an array of `INT64` s in `BigQuery` standard SQL from a column which is a long string of numbers separated by commas (for example, `2013,1625,1297,7634`). I can pull an array of strings easily with:

```
SELECT
  SPLIT(string_col,",")
FROM
  table
```

However, I want to return an array of `INT64` s, not an array of strings. How can I do that? I've tried

```
CAST(SPLIT(string_col,",") AS ARRAY<INT64>)
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2013,1625,1297,7634' AS string_col UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '1,2,3,4,5'
)
SELECT id, 
  (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(CAST(num AS INT64)) 
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(string_col)) AS num
  ) AS num,
  ARRAY(SELECT CAST(num AS INT64) 
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(string_col)) AS num
  ) AS num_2
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: You beat me to it :) Maybe demonstrate using an `ARRAY` subquery too? (That's what I was going to post).

Answer (score 0):

Mikhail beat me to it and his answer is more extensive but adding this as a more minimal repro:

```
SELECT CAST(num as INT64) from unnest(SPLIT("2013,1625,1297,7634",",")) as num;
```

Comment: Check this : "However, I want to return an **array** of INT64s" :o)