# Bigquery- Struct format

Tags: google-bigquery

```
WITH yourTable AS (
      SELECT 1 AS id, '2013,1625,1297,7634' AS string_col UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, '1,2,3,4,5'
    )

    SELECT id, 
      (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(CAST(num AS INT64)) 
        FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(string_col)) AS num
      ) AS num,
      ARRAY(SELECT CAST(num AS INT64) 
        FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(string_col)) AS num
      ) AS num_2
    FROM yourTable
```

[image]

This is how exactly my actual table is designed and Now I would like to multiply num*num_2 and then later sum it up. Is there a way to get this into struct format like ID, nums.num,nums.num_2 so that I can simply multiply which gives me the necessary result.

PS: I am looking for solution in the select statement above but not within "with" statement.

Comment: post that you borrowed above query - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45068831/5221944 - just shows two ways of doing the same result - one is using `(SELECT ARRAY ...)` and another using `ARRAY(SELECT ...)`. So can  you please explain what the logic that you are trying to achieve! is it summing of squares of elements for each id?

Comment: @Mikhail Berlyant Yup, I picked it from one of your solution as I have the same requirement where there are 3 string columns (ID, quantity, revenue). Where quantity and revenue are separated  with comma. Based on your solution I was able to get the quantity and revenue into array records and now I need to multiply quantity* revenue then sum per each ID.
Note: I am not looking to sum the squares. as the actual data contains different numbers

Comment: i see now  - s I think my below answer should work for you :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, assuming that you really have reason to have your table the way you have (see my comment on your question) - below should work

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT id, 
  (
    SELECT SUM(num * num_2)
    FROM (SELECT pos, num FROM UNNEST(num) num WITH OFFSET pos) a
    JOIN (SELECT pos_2, num_2 FROM UNNEST(num_2) num_2 WITH OFFSET pos_2) b
    ON a.pos = b.pos_2
  ) mul
FROM yourTable
```

you can test it with below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 id, [2013,1625,1297,7634] num, [2013,1625,1297,7634] num_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5] 
) 
SELECT id, 
  (
    SELECT SUM(num * num_2)
    FROM (SELECT pos, num FROM UNNEST(num) num WITH OFFSET pos) a
    JOIN (SELECT pos_2, num_2 FROM UNNEST(num_2) num_2 WITH OFFSET pos_2) b
    ON a.pos = b.pos_2
  ) mul
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It's working on the actual data too.

Comment: perfect. glad we did it :o)

Comment: I just posted a followup question to this. Appreciate your help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289696/bigquery-flatten-the-table-using-standard-sql