# Bigquery-Flatten the table using Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

Follow up to my before question Link-
[Bigquery- Struct format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272583/bigquery-struct-format)

This is my current table format in image -1, and I want to fetch details of Product B as shown in image-2 but not possible as it is in Array format.
So technically I want to flatten my table as shown in image-3. Is there any way that I can do it. Kindly advice.

[image: Image-1]

[image: Image-2]
[image: Image-3]

Sample query for image-1 table

```
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 id,["A","B","C","D"] Product, [2013,1625,1297,7634] num, [2013,1625,1297,7634] num_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,["A","B","C","D","E"] Product, [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5] 
) 


    SELECT id,Product,
      Array (
        SELECT num * num_2
        FROM (SELECT pos, num FROM UNNEST(num) num WITH OFFSET pos) a
        JOIN (SELECT pos_2, num_2 FROM UNNEST(num_2) num_2 WITH OFFSET pos_2) b
        ON a.pos = b.pos_2
      ) mul
    FROM yourTable
```

I am interested to see if can flatten it in "select" statement but not in "with" statement.

Revised query to get the result set which I am looking for.
Please suggest if there is any easy way.

```
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 id,["A","B","C","D"] Product, [2013,1625,1297,7634] num, [2013,1625,1297,7634] num_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,["A","B","C","D","E"] Product, [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5] 
) 
select id,product,num,num_2,mul
from

(select id,product,num,num_2,mul,pos,pos_2,pos_3,pos_4 

from

(SELECT id,Product,num,num_2,
  Array (
    SELECT num * num_2
    FROM (SELECT pos, num FROM UNNEST(num) num WITH OFFSET pos) a
    JOIN (SELECT pos_2, num_2 FROM UNNEST(num_2) num_2 WITH OFFSET pos_2) b
    ON a.pos = b.pos_2
  ) mul
FROM yourTable


), unnest(product) as product WITH OFFSET pos,
unnest (num) as num WITH OFFSET pos_2,
unnest (num_2) as num_2 WITH OFFSET pos_3,
unnest (mul) as mul WITH OFFSET pos_4) 

where pos=pos_2 and 
pos=pos_3
and pos=pos_4
```

Comment: @Mikhail Berlyant is there any way that you can help me out

Comment: can  you show what you tried so far! otherwise it looks that you just simply outsourcing your job and this site is not for this at all.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I'm sorry may be you might have mistaken. I did'nt work on Arrays before so bit confusing on that part. I am looking here to analyze data on product basis(Product) that has quantity and price. But products info,price and quantities are isolated from a string then using split function I could get that into a array format. Based on your previous suggestions I could get the revenue for each product by each i'd. If I want to analyze the data grouped by Product(image -2). I am unable to get it since the records are in array format. Kindly advice.

Comment: i got it. my question is  - what exactly you tried so far? show us some attempt on your side so we can help you rather than just do whole stuff for you

Comment: @Mikhail Berlyant I couldn't post the code in comment, hence updated the query above as a revised one. I could get the required result set but please suggest if there is any other easy way that I could fetch the same result. Appreciate your help

Comment: thank you @harish - yes having your code in question is exactly what expected (not in comments) - I will check it :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 id,["A","B","C","D"] Product, [2013,1625,1297,7634] num, [2013,1625,1297,7634] num_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,["A","B","C","D","E"] Product, [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5] 
) 
SELECT id, Product, num, num_2, num * num_2 mul
FROM yourTable, UNNEST(num) num WITH OFFSET pos
JOIN UNNEST(num_2) num_2 WITH OFFSET pos_2 ON pos = pos_2
JOIN UNNEST(Product) Product WITH OFFSET pos_3 ON pos = pos_3
```